# Python: merge nested lists

Tags: python, merge, nested-lists

beginner to python here.

I have 2 nested lists that I want to merge:

```
list1 = ['a',
         (b, c),
         (d, e),
         (f, g, h) ]

list2 = [(p,q),
         (r, s),
         (t),
         (u, v, w) ]
```

the output I am looking for is:

```
list3 = [(a, p, q),
         (b, c, r, s),
         (d, e, t),
         (f, g, h, u, v, w) ]
```

Can this be done without any external libraries?
note: len(list1) = len(list2)

Comment: *beginner to python here.* - This means you should read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Comment: Hi. I have read the tuts. I know how to merge simple lists. But don't know how to go about with nested lists.

Comment: Also, the first element of `list1` is a string in your example, but after the merge it seems to be an object.

Comment: ... which is valid if `a == 'a'`, but then the rest doesn't make any sense. `(t)` is not a tuple, btw. -1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the power of the [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list1 = [('a', ),
        ('b', 'c'),
        ('d', 'e'),
        ('f', 'g', 'h') ]

list2 = [('p', 'q'),
        ('r', 's'),
        ('t', ),
        ('u', 'v', 'w') ]

print [a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from operator import add
list3 = map(add, list1, list2)
```

Comment: Or, if you want to avoid the import, `map(tuple.__add__, ...)`. (+1 for not insisting on list comprehensions where `map()` is more readable.)

Answer (score 0):

If the order within an inner list/tuple is not important, you can use the mathematical set operations.

print [tuple(set(a)|set(b)) for a,b in zip(x,y)]

The set(a)|set(b) converts the iterables a and b to sets and takes the union of the two sets. They are then converted back to tuple as desired in the output format.

As you are a beginner to python, it is strongly recommended to master list comprehensions. It is way too powerful and concise. In addition to making your code more 'pythonic', list comprehensions can act as a friendlier replacement to 'map' and 'filter' functions.

Answer (score 0):

### Easy One

```
list_3 = []
list_3.extend(list_1 + list_2)
```