# How to join two list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, join

Suppose I am having two list of lists as :

```
a=[['10', '1', '10-08-2017'], ['10', '1', '27-07-2017']]

b=[['SKS', ' SKSIND '], ['Arcotech', ' ARCOTECH ']]
```

Expected output:

[['SKS', ' SKSIND ','10', '1', '10-08-2017'], ['Arcotech', ' ARCOTECH ','10', '1', '27-07-2017']]

What I am trying is:

```
s=[ a[i].extend(b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
print (s)
#[None, None]---Output
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: `list.exted()` changes the lists in-place, it doesn't return a new list. You can use `zip` and `add` operation instead.

Comment: Here is an exact duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806511/python-merge-nested-lists

Comment: Thanks it works now..

Comment: for i in range(len(a)):
  
  a[i].extend(b[i])
print (a)------[['SKS', ' SKSIND ', '10', '1', '10-08-2017'], ['Arcotech', ' ARCOTECH ', '10', '1', '27-07-2017']]